# How to apply the com.android.application plugin using the new plugins DSL?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project configured through the triple of:

- Declare repository in top-level **build.gradle**:

  ```
  buildscript { repositories { google() }}
  allprojects { repositories { google() }}
  ```
- Declare classpath dependency, so plugin artifact gets downloaded from the appropriate repository, in top-level **build.gradle**

  ```
  buildscript { dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' }}
  ```
- Then, in the app **build.gradle** file, apply the plugin:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  ```

I want to migrate this to use the [new plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) as enabled by the [`PluginsDependenciesSpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html).

I then:

- Declared the repository in **settings.gradle**:

  ```
  pluginManagement { repositories { google() }}
  ```
- Declared the plugin dependency in the app **build.gradle**:

  ```
  plugins { id "com.android.application" version "3.1.3" }
  ```

But this fails to resolve:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '…/build.gradle' line: 2
> - What went wrong: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '3.1.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:3.1.3')
>
> Searched in the following repositories:
>
> - Google
> - BintrayJCenter
> - maven(https://maven.fabric.io/public)
> - Gradle Central Plugin Repository

What am I missing to get Gradle to connect the dots here, so that it can connect the plugin.id to the appropriate JAR fetched from the appropriate repository?

Answer (score 1):

Within the `pluginManagement` you can use `resolutionStrategy` and force usage of specific artifact from the `google()` repository.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id in ['com.android.application', 'com.android.library']) {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${getProperty('version.plugin.android')}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can apply android plugins with using new `plugins` DSL:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

or

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_resolution_rules).